# Checking reversed text on C++ (doesn't work with a -1 index?)

Tags: c++

I was making a simple palindrome checker and can't understand why the iterator works with index 0,  but won't work with index -1, you can see that both codes print the SAME text, but not the same boolean.

Can anyone explain me what's the logic behind this?

The only different part on both codes is this:

> for(int i=text.size();i>=**-1**;i--) *Not Working*
> for(int i=text.size()**-1**;i>=**0**;i--) *Working*

**WORKING:**

---

```
#include <iostream>

// Define is_palindrome() here:
std::string is_palindrome(std::string text){
  std::string reverse= "";
  for(int i=text.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    reverse += text[i];
  }
  if(reverse == text){

    return text + " IS palindrome (reverse text: " + reverse +")";
  } else {

    return text + " NOT palindrome (reverse text: " + reverse + ")";
  }
}

int main() {
  
  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";
  
}
```

**output**

```
madam IS palindrome (reverse text: madam)
ada IS palindrome (reverse text: ada)
lovelace NOT palindrome (reverse text: ecalevol)
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
#include <iostream>

// Define is_palindrome() here:
std::string is_palindrome(std::string text){
  std::string reverse= "";
  for(int i=text.size();i>=-1;i--){
    reverse += text[i];
  }
  if(reverse == text){

    return text + " IS palindrome (reverse text: " + reverse +")";
  } else {

    return text + " NOT palindrome (reverse text: " + reverse + ")";
  }
}

int main() {

  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";

}
```

**output**

```
madam NOT palindrome (reverse text: madam)
ada NOT palindrome (reverse text: ada)
lovelace NOT palindrome (reverse text: ecalevol)
```

Comment: If text is of size `N`, then `text[N]` is out of bounds. `text[-1]` is out of bounds no matter the size. Your second  loop is the correct loop. What is your question?

Comment: I assume you are new to c++ and is coming from python. c/c++ doesn't support negative index as python does (also no index splicing).

Comment: Also, there is an easy way of reversing a string. It's the `std::reverse()` function. Works great with string.

Comment: @sagi the code is working , check the output. if it was out of bounds it wouldn't even compile

Comment: Or, if you don't want in place, `std::string::insert(this.end(), other.rbegin(), other.rend())`.

Comment: @DaviAreias The first part of your question has the `i>=-1` loop as the first loop, but later the code snippets have the `i>=0` loop as the first loop. That will confuse everyone when talking about first and second loop...

Comment: The compiler can't know that the indexing will be out of bounds.

Comment: @Davi - sagi explains why the non-working version is not working.  :-) The difference is not in the for-loop, but in the indexing. When you start at `i = text.size()`, you are immediately out of bounds.

Comment: In c++ container classes use index differently from conventional arrays. In short, the index never fails even if it's out of bound (unchecked). But out of bound indices won't show error and compile but will very definitely give weird outputs.

Comment: @AbdurRakib, what do you mean by "the index never fails even if it's out of bound"?

Comment: Do you expect both versions to work? Why? Explain the reason why you think the difference is not important.

Comment: @kuro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373289/does-string-in-c-have-no-out-of-bound-exeption-error

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I want to understand why both versions print the same text and reversed text, but print different booleans

Comment: one is wrong and the other is correct. Wrong code can print correct results by chance.

Comment: This is called `undefined behaviour`. @DaviAreias, you can't understand it, because as the name suggests, it's undefined.

Comment: @sagi, uh. I misunderstood his comments. stupid of me

Comment: @kuro, for container classes. For example, say there is a vector `v` with size `100`. Then out of bound indices like `v[-1]`, `v[100]`, `v[200]` etc. won't give any error but will return weird values. But for conventional arrays like `int arr[100]=//something`, `arr[-1]`, `arr[100]` etc. will give compile-time error.

Comment: Both versions *print* the same text, but it doesn't mean it *is* the same text. Strings may contain unprintable characters. To be absolutely sure about the content of the string, you need to print each character individually. Print printable characters as is, print numeric codes in place of unprintable characters. (Actually doing this is not extremely useful in this particular case, because you know where undefined behaviour is. But it is generally useful if you see strange string-related behaviour).

Comment: @AbdurRakib "will give compile-time error" It may, or it may not, depending on lots of things. There is no such requirement in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ uses 0-based indexing, ie valid indices of a `N` sized container are `0,1,2...N-1`. If you try to use an index out of bounds your code invokes undefined behavior.

Look at the output of this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string& text){
    for(int i=text.size();i>=-1;i--){
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    foo("madam");
}
```

It is

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
```

Both `-1` and `5` are not elements of the string, because it has only `5` characters. (For `5` I am allowing myself to simplify the matter a bit, because strings have some oddities for accessing the one past last character null terminator. As `-1` definitely is out of bounds and with `std::string` you usually need not deal with the null terminator explicitly, this is ok for this answer).

Now look at the output of this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string& text){
    for(int i=text.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    foo("madam");
}
```

It is

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

It iterates all characters of the input string. Thats why this is correct and the other is wrong.

When your code has undefined behavior anything can happen. The results may appear to be correct or partially correct. Wrong code does not necessarily produce obviously wrong output.

Note that `for(int i=text.size()-1;i>=0;i--)` is a problem when the size of the string is `0`, because `size()` returns an unsigned which wraps around to result in a large positive number. You can avoid that by using iterators instead. There are reverse iterators that make a reverse loop look the same as a forward loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {    
    std::string text("123");
    for (auto i = text.rbegin(); i != text.rend(); ++i) std::cout << *i;
}
```

Output

```
321
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by 463035818_is_not_a_number, you can also construct a string from another string using iterators:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {    
    std::string text("123");
    std::string rev(crbegin(text), crend(text));
    std::cout << rev << '\n';
}
```

And there's [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {    
    std::string text("123");
    reverse(begin(text), end(text));
    std::cout << text << '\n';
}
```

But for a palindrome, you don't have to compare two whole strings. You just need to see of the first half of the string is equal to the reverse of the last half of the string.